Set of elements $w$ so that the sequence of random variables $\left(X(w)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge
Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. For any $b \in \mathbb{R}$, I can prove that$$\mathcal{F}_{b} = \{ \omega \colon X_n(\omega) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} b \}$$is an event, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{b}$ is measurable (actually it is a tail event) since$$\mathcal{F}_{b} = \bigcap\limits_{n > 0} \bigcup\limits_{l \geq 0} \bigcap\limits_{k \geq l}\left(\left|X_k - b \right| \leq \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
But I struggle to expand this result to a measurable set $B \in \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$: is $$\mathcal{F}_{B} = \bigcup\limits_{b \in B}\mathcal{F}_{b}$$measurable?

Your question is independent of the definition of the set $\mathcal F_b$. There is no reason that a non-countable union of measurable set is measurable.

@Surb, thank you. In the general, this union should not be mesurable, but I wonder for this special case.

It is actually simple. Define$$\begin{align}Y & \colon \omega \mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup X_{n}(\omega) \\ Z & \colon \omega \mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \inf X_{n}(\omega)\end{align}$$then $Y,Z$ are measurable functions. Moreover $$\mathcal{F}_{B} = Y^{-1}\left(B\right) \bigcap \left(Y = Z\right)$$so $\mathcal{F}_{B}$ is measurable.
